# Understanding the ErrorT monad transformer

Tags: haskell

```
newtype ErrorT e m a = ErrorT { runErrorT :: m (Either e a) }

instance (Monad m, Error e) => Monad (ErrorT e m) where

    return a = ErrorT $ return (Right a)

    m >>= k = ErrorT $ do
        a <- runErrorT m
        case a of
            Left l -> return (Left l)
            Right r -> runErrorT (k r)

    fail msg = ErrorT $ return (Left (strMsg msg))
```

Let's consider above piece of code. It makes me trouble to understand it. How does it work in context of Monads/Transormer Monads? Especially, the problem is understanding why `return a = ErrorT $ return (Right a)` return `return (Right a)`. I don't understand why just it.

The second issue. `m >>= k` is basically understood by me ( I hope so ;) )but why in `Right r -> runErrorT (k r)` appeared runError?

Comment: As an exercise, try writing the instance yourself, from scratch, using GHC's typed holes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ErrorT` is just a wrapper. That is, the type `ErrorT e m a` is isomorphic to the type `m (Either e a)`: the latter can be converted into the former by the constructor `ErrorT`, while its associated destructor `runErrorT` converts in the other direction.

The definitions of `return` and `>>=` must wrap/unwrap values to respect the types. This wrapping/unwrapping has no concrete effect at run time, it is just there so that the program type checks and the compiler can choose the correct monad instance (`m` or `ErrorT e m`, depending on whether a value it's wrapped).

Here

```
return a = ErrorT $ return (Right a)
```

the part `return (Right a)` has type `m (Either e a)`, but we want `ErrorT e m a` instead. Applying `ErrorT` fixes that.

Similarly, in this code:

```
m >>= k = ErrorT $ do
    a <- runErrorT m
    case a of
        Left l -> return (Left l)
        Right r -> runErrorT (k r)
```

we need to return `ErrorT m e b`. This is done by using `ErrorT` applied to some value of type `m (Either e b)`. The part `Left l` has type `Either e b`, so `return` adds the last `m` on top. Instead the part `k r` has type `ErrorT e m b`, so we need to unwrap it with `runErrorT` (so that the whole `do` can be rewrapped again).

Comment: "the latter can be converted into the former by the constructor ErrorT"
What do you mean by that? ( especially by 'former')

Comment: @Gilgamesz It means values of type `m (Either e a)` can be converted to values of type `ErrorT e m a` using the constructor `ErrorT` whose type is precisely `m (Either e a) -> ErorrT e m a`.

Comment: Why     `a <- runErrorT m`. Why there is parameter `m` for `runErrorT`? Though, `runErrorT` is argumentless

Comment: @Gilgamesz No, `runErrorT` takes a wrapped value of type `ErrorT e m a` and unwraps it exposing the internal type `m (Either e a)`. Ask GHCi about its type.

Comment: " takes a wrapped value of type `ErrorT e m a`". I didn't know that. It was a problem. It takes that because of definition: `newtype ErrorT e m a = ErrorT { runErrorT :: m (Either e a) }`?

Comment: @Gilgamesz Yes, precisely. When you use `newtype T = K { unK :: S }` you automatically get a wrapping constructor `K :: S -> T` and an unwrapping destructor `unK :: T -> S`. This kind of wrapping/unwrapping is very commonly used when newtypes are involved.